# Ajax button not working in asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an MVC ASP.NET app in C#, and I need to add a button event in order to do something.

So following some tutorial I tried this in the .cshtml file:

```
<button>Next</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Accounts/Btn_Click",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Ok");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

By the way, clicking the button, nothing happens... so, is there something I missed?
Also with debugging, I see that clicking the button, the method "Btn_Click" is not even called.
Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Here's the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Btn_Click()
{
    return Content("Ok");

}
```

It's basically empty. I was trying to see if the method was at least called, and with debug I've seen it is not called.

Comment: Can you share the HTML of button? You also might want it use error callback in Ajax to see if there are any errors returned from the server.

Comment: Can you post the controller endpoint you're trying to hit?

Comment: I tried both the <button>Name</button> as i posted befor, and also with <input>type=button id="btn_id"</input>  but same result

Comment: If the button is not being hit at all. Have you verified the jQuery plugin and everything is loaded on the page correctly.

Comment: open the browser developer console and see if there's any scripting error

Comment: I'm assuming the controller name matches too?

Comment: Thanks @RyanThomas, that was the problem, sorry for my newbie error, i'm new to this stuff.

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it. I had the same issue with my first MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class or an id to the button and then wiring that up.

```
<button id="next-btn">Next</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next-btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Accounts/Btn_Click",
            success: function () {
                alert("Ok");
            }
        });
    });
});
```